# MVC View Images and Video Located On Android Tablet

Tags: c#, android, asp.net-mvc

I've been building a production level application using MVC and have recently added a WebRTC GetUserMedia() module which allows users to capture pictures and video. Pictures come out pretty good. Video isn't too bad either if you do not move the camera, but as soon as you move the camera like in a pan... even moving it slowly video quality goes down hill really fast. That isn't going to work for capturing production level footage designed for QA.

I've tried to research third party tools to where I can take picture's and video's natively... but everything I've found seems to be old articles and plugins whose final output eventually became GetUserMedia() from what I can determine. I was brainstorming some ideas like:

1. Using Electron.js. However in my brief research it seems developers seem to be pointing towards WebRTC as well? Is their not a native API to access device functions like PhoneGap using Electron?
2. My second idea which I believe to be the best is to skip everything and just use the devices camera app to take pictures and video. But in order to get this to work the way I need it I need to access the path to the native devices default image/ video folder.

I am not familiar with how to access a folder on an Android Tablet. Is there a C# function like:

```
String GalleryPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyMedia);
```

Even if there were a method like this would this work on an Android tablet? Is it possible to hard code a path to a local mobile device? If so, how would this be done?

Comment: No sure about your third party issues but for here's example code for getting a folder from Android:
File SAVE_DIR = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);

Is it possible to hard code a path on a mobile device? Yes.
Similar to C# but instead of "C:\Programs\Etc" it looks something like "/data/app/{appname}/{folders related to app}"

Comment: Wow comments have no formatting. Not easy to read at all but if you're used to C# then Java is very easy to pick up as it is **very** similar.

Comment: @C.Carter Beautiful, exactly what I was looking for! Please provide as an answer so that I can award it. I thought it should be possible but was worried that it might not. I created an RTC Windows Store App some years ago back in the Windows 8 Days and remember having frustrations about limitations to the local file system and didn't know if it was a mobile thing or not.

Comment: You can also use Xamarin as well which allows you to write C# code for Android. Later versions use .Net Standard which means you can write cross platform code libraries relatively easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's example code for getting a folder from Android:

```
File SAVE_DIR = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
```

Is it possible to hard code a path on a mobile device? Yes. Similar to C# but instead of:

"C:\Programs\Etc"

it looks something like

"/data/app/{appname}/{folders related to app}"

Answer (score 0):

This was the first project that I had tried to integrate a mobile devices camera so it was a learning experience. I actually did not using the example I awarded as I came up with a completely simpler approach for what I was trying to accomplish overall. I am just posting this for others to avoid making the same mistakes I had made. I awarded the other answer because it allowed me to know that it was possible. Also of note is that the [Environment.SpecialFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx) has multiple new (at least new to me) enumerations that are now available for locating these directories... I think they would work on the Android platform as well but I didn't get a chance to test it. In this case I would have used the `CommonPictures` and the `CommonVideos` enumerations to accomplish what I was looking for.

**What I Used:** My idea was that instead of taking pictures and video from the browser using WebRTC that I would just use the devices camera and then process the pictures and videos from my app from the devices media directory... which is why I was looking for a way to locate the directory to begin with. Once I discovered it could be done, I had actually began looking for a way to open the devices camera from C# when I came across this [article](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/asp-net/taking-pictures-html/) that changed my whole approach. It dawned on me in this article because he had mobile screen shots from the mobile device! In the end I was able to accomplish pretty much all I was looking for with one line of HTML:
 `<input id="CapturedMedia" name="CapturedMedia" type="file" accept="audio/*,video/*,image/*" onchange="UploadMedia()">`

In my research I had come across this multiple times, in fact I've used the  element multiple times myself to upload files into my ASP.Net apps. But I had always used this element from a desktop computer in which it activates the Open File Dialog. I had no idea that from a mobile device it could automatically open the devices camera and allow you to take picture and video from the devices camera. In researching how to take pictures and video from your web app all you read about is doing this directly from the browser via WebRTC MediaCapture because it's the new kid on the block and it's all the buzz. But whats new isn't always whats best and I feel in most cases that I would only use MediaCapture if I was trying to take pictures and video from a desktop... I would not use it for a mobile device.